# i can’t log in the ios app

Tags: bug, login

[image: this the error]
I can’t login the ios app, how to fix this problem? Neither the overflow nor the exchange.

Comment: If you are trying to log in from China, maybe this problem is related to the [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)?

Comment: If this affects multiple sites, it might be more efficient to ask on https://meta.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Is it the iOS app, or Safari on iPhone? These two things are different.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl It just happens these days.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila ios app

Comment: Cross-site dupe on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376216/unable-to-login-to-the-so-ios-app-with-google (not fixed yet)